# How to create vertically typeset sections in a horizontally typed document in LuaLaTex for CJKV languages?

Tags: luatex, cjk

How would I go about creating vertical Chinese/Japanese sections (perhaps boxed) in a horizontally typed document.

Something like the Kanbun sections in this documentation: https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/kanbun/kanbun-en.pdf

[image]